# NullReferenceException C# adding to dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-3.5

Here is a cut down snippet of the code. Both tupleUnits.Key and tupleR are non-null objects.

```
public partial class AllLicenseeUnits : System.Web.UI.Page {
  protected Dictionary<int, TupleRecordsRange> unitsInTuple = new Dictionary<int, TupleRecordsRange>();

  public Paginator getPaginator(int itemsPerPage) {
    if (unitsInTuple == null) {
        Dictionary<int, int> tuplesUnits = DataAccess.CountLicenseeUnitsTuple(Session["licensee"] as Licensee);
        tuplesUnits = tuplesUnits.Where(item => item.Value > 0).ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value); 
        int index = 0;
        foreach(KeyValuePair<int, int> tupleUnits in tuplesUnits) {
            TupleRecordsRange tupleR =  new TupleRecordsRange{start_index = index, end_index= (index + tupleUnits.Value -1)};
            unitsInTuple.Add(tupleUnits.Key, tupleR);
            index += tupleUnits.Value;
        }
    }
    int sumUnits = unitsInTuple.Sum(item => item.Value.totalRecords);
    Paginator paginator = new Paginator(itemsPerPage, sumUnits);
    if (Request.QueryString["page"] != null)
    {
        paginator.currentPage = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["page"]);
    }
    return paginator;
  }
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening since both the perameters I pass into .Add() are not null.
Here are the watches:

```
-       tupleUnits  {[1, 3081]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,int>

+       tupleR  {AllLicenseeUnits.TupleRecordsRange}    AllLicenseeUnits.TupleRecordsRange
```

Stack Trace:

```
  at AllLicenseeUnits.getPaginator(Int32 itemsPerPage) in C:\Users\User\Documents\Bla_Devel\AllLicenseeUnits.aspx.cs:line 46
   at AllLicenseeUnits.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\User\Documents\Bla_Devel\AllLicenseeUnits.aspx.cs:line 32
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: What exactly is `tuplesUnits`?

Comment: @Jeff it's a  Dictionary<int, int>. I've added more code above.

Comment: Which line of code actually generates the `NullReferenceException`?  Usually those are pretty easy to fix, just put a breakpoint on that line and debug it.

Comment: @SLaks Track trace above. @Samuel, It's the `unitsInTuple.Add(...` line. I am familiar with debugging, but since I cannot step down any deeper and both parameters are not null it's confusing me. I'm not trying to waste anyone's time here, I did google it, and attempt to debug before coming here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you haven't created the dictionary before you add to it.

```
if (unitsInTuple == null) {
            ...
            unitsInTuple.Add(tupleUnits.Key, tupleR);
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: UnitsInTuple is created on the second line.

Comment: Thanks, I've realised assigning a new object into unitsInTuple it from the class scope didn't actually do anything. But when I assigned it from the method it works. At least that is my understanding.

Comment: It should be initialised from the example you posted - My guess is that it is being set to null elsewhere in the class.

Comment: @saus. Indeed it was. It all makes sense now. Thanks.